# Substring should return Distinct values

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have a name column like this:

```
Name
------
Roger
RogerMan
Roger That
```

I need a query which would return distinct initials from the column. For example, in this case I want to return:

```
Name
-----
R
RM
RT
```

I have tried a number of approaches for this:
1. CASE statement (works perfectly by far).
2. STRCMP
3. SUBSTRING

However, I am looking for a more dynamic approach using functions in Postgres.

Comment: Garfield, in your example, you will have two rows, R and RT because RogerMan being one word will just return R as its initial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `regexp_replace()` to remove all non capital alphabetic characters from the string, like so:

```
 regexp_replace(name, '[^A-Z]', '', 'g')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=46a5425328b068e1a4f23a37d2934571)**:

```
with t(name) as (
    select 'Roger'
    union all select 'RogerMan'
    union all select 'Roger That'
)
select name, regexp_replace(name, '[^A-Z]', '', 'g') initials from t
```

```
name       | initials
:--------- | :-------
Roger      | R       
RogerMan   | RM      
Roger That | RT
```